# How to check if the input string is a valid VB string?

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

We know that VB string start and end with double quotes " "

So we have to use "" if we want " in VB string.

I wonder if there is a regular expression pattern which will match VB string?.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? String values in Visual Basic do not begin nor end with double-quotes, although double-quotes may be part of a string. Any value in an application can be converted to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to detect if the string they entered would be valid if typed into a VB code file?  If so the following regular expression should do the trick

```
^"(("")|[^"])*"$
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the context here? You only need to escape quotes to let the compiler distinguish between start/end quotes and quotes which are part of the string data. If the string is read during runtime there's no need for double quotes.